How to extract string content of JObject as is?
Look at this code
Dim jsonString As String = "{
    ""uuid"": ""4b84ca0c-40c8-4c2e-b1af-ddd727f3d0cf"",
    ""side"": ""bid"",
    ""ord_type"": ""limit"",
    ""price"": ""0.00000012"",
    ""state"": ""wait"",
    ""market"": ""BTC-RLY"",
    ""created_at"": ""2024-07-12T07:27:12Z"",
    ""volume"": ""121638.62897338"",
    ""remaining_volume"": ""121638.62897338"",
    ""reserved_fee"": ""0.00006714452319330576"",
    ""remaining_fee"": ""0.00006714452319330576"",
    ""paid_fee"": ""0"",
    ""locked"": ""0.01466377999999890576"",
    ""executed_volume"": ""0"",
    ""trades_count"": 0,
    ""base123"": ""BTC"",
    ""quote123"": ""RLY""
}"

Dim b1 As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
Dim createdAt As String = b1("created_at").Value(Of String) '07/12/2024 07:27:12
Dim createdAt1 As String = b1("created_at").ToString '7/12/2024 7:27:12 AM
Dim createdAt2 As String = "2024-07-12T07:27:12Z" '<- how do I get that?

The resulting value of createdAt is:
"07/12/2024 07:27:12"

And the resulting value of createdAt1 is:
"7/12/2024 7:27:12 AM"

The original value is:
"2024-07-12T07:27:12Z"

How do I get the value in that exact original string format?
Curiously
b1.tostring shows
{
  "uuid": "4b84ca0c-40c8-4c2e-b1af-ddd727f3d0cf",
  "side": "bid",
  "ord_type": "limit",
  "price": "0.00000012",
  "state": "wait",
  "market": "BTC-RLY",
  "created_at": "2024-07-12T07:27:12Z",
  "volume": "121638.62897338",
  "remaining_volume": "121638.62897338",
  "reserved_fee": "0.00006714452319330576",
  "remaining_fee": "0.00006714452319330576",
  "paid_fee": "0",
  "locked": "0.01466377999999890576",
  "executed_volume": "0",
  "trades_count": 0,
  "base123": "BTC",
  "quote123": "RLY"
}

So the original "2024-07-12T07:27:12Z" string is still there.

Does JToken: Get raw/original JSON value answer your question?  The answers there are in C# not VB.NET.

The DateTime parsing is already done here:
JObject.Parse(jsonString)

So any fetching of the result afterward will always end up with a parsed DateTime value.  I don't know if the settings for the JObject.Parse() method have this option somewhere, but JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() has an option to ignore Date parsing and treat the property as a string.
For example:
Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None}
Dim b1 = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, settings), JObject)

Dim createdAt As String = b1("created_at")

The resulting value of createdAt is:
"2024-07-12T07:27:12Z"


There is this constructor for JObject.Parse
    public new static JObject Parse(string json, JsonLoadSettings? settings)

Not sure how to use that

@user4951: If you're referring to JsonLoadSettings specifically, I see only limited options in the documentation that I found.  The JsonSerializerSettings object has more robust options.

I don't know if I should ask another question or add supplementary answer to @David answer
I actually write these 3 functions
Public Shared Function JTokenParse(jsonstring As String) As JToken
    Static settings As JsonSerializerSettings = Nothing
    If settings Is Nothing Then
        settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None}
    End If
    Dim b1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring, settings)
    Dim b = CType(b1, JToken)
    Return b
End Function

Public Shared Function jObjectParse(jsonstring As String) As JObject
    Dim b = JTokenParse(jsonstring)
    Dim b1 = CType(b, JObject)
    Return b1
End Function

Public Shared Function jArrayParse(jsonstring As String) As JArray
    Dim b = JTokenParse(jsonstring)
    Dim b1 = CType(b, JArray)
    Return b1
End Function

They replace JToken.parse, JObject.parse, and JArray.parse respectively.
It seems that there is no other way.
If we do not want newtonsoft to stupidly automatically parse date the only way is to use jsonserializersettings and that's only available at deserializeobject and not on JObject.parse.
Is it a good idea? Should this be another question?
